# add path when installing mpich in ubuntu

Tags: linux, mpi

I know there are many tips online about installing mpich2 in linux/ubuntu, but I just do not know how to add path so that each .c/.f90 file can see the 'mpif.h'.

I think I have successfully installed mpich2 on my machine. Because when I run

```
mpiexec -np 3 ./cpi
```

It works. `cpi` is a application in the 'example' file. But when I tried to run `gcc -o mpitest hellow.c`. It always said `undefined reference to MPI_INIT` and some similar errors.

The `mpiexec mpirun` are in `/usr/local/bin` and `mpif.h mpi.h`are in `/usr/local/include`. So how to add path?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to add a anything to your PATH. What you need to do is to link your application with the MPI libraries.

MPI installations provide a useful wrapper for this. Simply replace `gcc` by `mpicc`:

```
mpicc -o mpitest hellow.c
```